# Calculate previous value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

A source is a visit if for the row above (1) the company above is the same company and (2) that type is home. The dataframe is sorted. But relying on the previous row means if there are rows in between, a visit is not being classified: here, row 1 is getting in the away row 2 being a visit. How could I classify these visits as long as the difference in time is within 5 minutes?

```
    source datetime location  type  start  company 
0          10:00    london    home  1       apple
1          10:03    unknown                 tesla
2          10:04    France                  apple
3          10:05    Melbourne home  1       apple
4    visit 10:06    France                  apple
```

10.04 is within 5 minutes of 10.00 so row 2 should be a visit. It also meets the 2 conditions of a visit.
Expected Output

```
    source datetime location  type  start  company 
0          10:00    london    home  1       apple
1          10:03    unknown                 tesla
2    visit 10:04    France                  apple
3          10:05    Melbourne home  1       apple
4    visit 10:06    France                  apple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
#create a reference date, with datetime where source is 'home'  
df['ref_date'] = df[df['type'].str.strip() !='']['datetime']

#downfill the ref_date grouping by company
df['ref_date']=df.groupby('company')['ref_date'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)

# use np.where to populate the source, where datetime and ref-date are different
# and the time difference is 5 mins or less

df['source']=np.where(  ((df['datetime']!=df['ref_date']) &
           ((pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df['ref_date'])).dt.total_seconds()/60) <=5)), 
         'visit',df['source'])

df=df.drop(columns='ref_date')
df
```

```
    source  datetime    location    type    start   company
0              10:00    london      home    1.0     apple
1              10:03    unknown                     tesla
2   visit      10:04    France                      apple
3              10:05    Melbourne   home    1.0     apple
4   visit      10:06    France                      apple
```